# PHP returning only null values from MySQL field on LEFT Join, while MySQL terminal functions as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running the following query;

```
SELECT a.user_id
     , u.username
     , p.person_name
  FROM activity a
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = a.user_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN persons p
    ON p.person_name = a.person_name
```

Both `u.username` AND `p.person_name` may be `null`. In the MySQL terminal, any `user_id` which has a non-null value for `username` or `person_name` are returned correctly. In the event where either are set to `null`, then MySQL will return as expected with `null`.

However, running this query through PHP7.2.0 returns with **all** `null` values on `person_name`, and `user_id`.

I've attempted to run this query both with a raw MySQLi query, and through CodeIgniter3's Active Record. Both return with all `null` values for the joined fields.

Is there anything I'm missing here which would force PHP to retrieve only `null` values on a nullable field?

Comment: Can I see the php portion of your question?

Comment: Without seeing the PHP it's impossible to answer the question.

Comment: In CI, tested using both the Active Record system, and as a plain query function - so, $sql = {above_sql}; var_dump($this-db->query($sql)->result_array());

Comment: We need the php code to helpyou.

Comment: I think some sample data nof for tables are more useful than the php code. I remark: I feeling not very well when I see that you join Persons and activity by a string value. If there are any difference between them ( a spche an ending, lower,uppercase and so on ) it will not work! but null = null is always true! So you will join all rows from person with name = null to all rows of activity with name = null, I think it not what you want!